# Warning message using yolov5

Tags: python, pytorch, yolov5

i am trying using yolov5 but recently i got warning message like this:

WARNING  'ultralytics.yolo.v8' is deprecated since '8.0.136' and will be removed in '8.1.0'. Please use 'ultralytics.models.yolo' instead.

WARNING  'ultralytics.yolo.utils' is deprecated since '8.0.136' and will be removed in '8.1.0'. Please use 'ultralytics.utils' instead.

Note this warning may be related to loading older models. You can update your model to current structure with:

```
    import torch
    ckpt = torch.load("model.pt")  # applies to both official and custom models
    torch.save(ckpt, "updated-model.pt")
```

the problem is i dont using any of ultralytics.yolo.v8 and ulralytics.yolo.utils in my code

```
import torch
import cv2 as cv

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print(device)

# Reload model
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')
```

the rest is just basic opencv to open camera, is anyone know what a problem is or the problem is from yolov5 repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i dont using any of ultralytics.yolo.v8 and ulralytics.yolo.utils in my code

As it says, "Note this warning may be related to loading older models", which **is** what you're doing. The model file you're loading using `torch.hub.load` contains references to the old module name.

You can ignore the warning for now, but using that model will break if you update the ultralytics module to 8.1+.

Comment: i tried to change to `torch.load('yolov5s')` but it get an error instead.

Comment: I don't know why you'd try to do that.

Comment: uhm to resolve the warning message, so what can i do to fix the issue then?

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. It does tell you what you _could_ do, but again, you do not need to do anything; things will still work for now. Maybe someday someone will update the torch hub file to the new module syntax.

Comment: I did what it said to fix it but the model that gets saved (while performing the same) still gives the warning message.  :(

Comment: Also I just discovered that you get this warning message if you simply `import yolov5` but don't do anything with the import!